# Elkies' supersingularity theorem in higher dimension (in terms of the associated Newton polygon)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, characteristic-p, calabi-yau

Elkies' supersingularity theorem: Given an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $E$ is supersingular over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I have seen [another post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8003/elkies-supersingularity-theorem-in-higher-dimension) on MathOverflow asking about higher dimensional analogues of Elkies theorem. However, that post only explores the higher-dimensional analog of supersingularity as the action of Frobenius being 0.

---

Recall that the Newton polygon of an elliptic curve may either be of slope 1 (corresponding to a supersingular elliptic curve) or have slope 0 then slope 2 (corresponding to an ordinary elliptic curve).

[image: Newton polygons associated to elliptic curves][(source of picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxnsp.png)

---

What happens when we take "supersingular" to mean "Newton polygon of shortest distance" such that there are different degrees of supersingularity (corresponding to the possible slopes of the Newton polygon of $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$)?

Let $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ be supersingular of degree $a$ if $$a = \text{length of the Newton polygon} - \text{number of segments of slope 0}$$

**Here's my question:** Let $C$ be an abelian variety (or Calabi-Yau manifold) over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Fix $a \in \{1, ..., 2g\}$. Are there an infinite number of primes such that $C$ is degree $a$ supersingular over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: On the one hand, it's implicit in the answer to the other question that, for a general abelian variety of dimension $\ge 3$, we don't even know how to prove that there are infinitely many ordinary primes (the expected generic case). Hence it's hard to imagine any sort of positive result. On the other hand, the answer is obviously no in general if $C$ has extra symmetries: for example, if $C = E \times E$ for any elliptic curve, then $a \ne 1$.

Comment: NB. Traditionally, an abelian variety is called supersingular if its Newton polygon is a straight line (of slope $1/2$), equivalently if it is isogenous to a power of a supersingular elliptic curve.